# Optimizing a recursive category and subcategory function in javascript with ES6

Tags: javascript, arrays, ecmascript-6

I have the following array

```
const categories = [
    {id:1,name:'Electronics',parent_id:0},
    {id:2,name:'Food',parent_id:0},
    {id:3,name:'Laptops',parent_id:1},
    {id:4,name:'Torches',parent_id:1},
];
```

So at the end of it all I expect to get an array of the following nature

```
const final_array = [
    {id:1, name:'Electronics', children: [
        {id:3,name:'Laptops',parent_id:1},
        {id:4,name:'Torches',parent_id:1},
    ]},
    {id:2, name:'Food'}
]
```

That is create parent child array

So i have written the following which works

```
  getNestedChildren(arr, parent) {
    var out = []
    for(var i in arr) {
      if(arr[i].parent_id === parent) {
        var children = this.getNestedChildren(arr, arr[i].id)

        if(children.length) {
          arr[i].children = children
        }
        out.push(arr[i])
      }
    }
    return out
  },
```

So by calling `this.getNestedChildren(categories,0)` this works

I would like to further optimize this function in es6. How can i go on about optimizing this function `getNestedChildren` further?

Comment: It's pretty well optimized. Only things I can see is instead of the for...in you're using, to use the traditional for loop, because it's the fastest one as far as I know. Other than that, you could use a fat arrow function and change all your vars to const or let appropriately for everything but that's not optimization. That's just a more modern way of doing it. However, be careful of your `this`, because the fat arrow function is treating it differently. Please let me know if I'm making sense. Fat arrow: 
`let getNestedChildren = (arr, parent) => {
 //code here
}`

Comment: Makes sense but since the function will be used in different components i have extracted this to a single js file (to reduce code duplications). So that i can simply import the javascript file and call the function in respective components. Hence the need to use getNestedChildren function than the fat arrow.

Comment: could there be another item which is a child of id=3?  If so, I think i have some ideas as well.  Also, is each id unique (a primary key) ?  If so, I think i have some good choices.